# what is indicator-netspeed-unity alternative for ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10

How can i show the bandwith in ubuntu 17.10?

This was so beautiful.

[image]

Comment: You still can install `unity` package. It is in repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Two I found quickly are both gnome extensions:

[Simple NetSpeed](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1085/simple-net-speed/)

[NetSpeed](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/)

Neither looks exactly like the one you had...

Comment: but both of these are ugly for me. I wanted that indicator netspeed to work for me.

Comment: @nazar2sfive Beauty is in the eye of the beholder...  `indicator-netspeed-unity` does not seem to be available in the repositories, and the source on github seems to have not been updated in a couple of years.